# CGI - Good Design Practice: setattr/eval/if-then?

Tags: python, cgi, eval

I have a question about good practice. In developing a back-end for my company, wherein our sales staff can manage clients remotely, I want them to simply be able to click "Edit Contact Info." (for instance) and have the python script "manageClients.py" call the "editContactInfo" function.

Obviously, the easiest way to do this would be to href `manageClients.pyfunction=editContactInfo&client=ClientName`

and in the script, after getting a fieldstorage instance:

```
if function:
      eval(function)
```

However, everything I see says to not use eval if it can be avoided. I don't fully understand setattr(), and I don't really know how I would work it into such a simple script. I also think `if function=="editClientInfo`: (and so on) would be way too bulky.

Obviously the code/URL stuff listed above is simplistic so I could clearly ask the question. There are security measures in place, etc.

I just want a way to tackle this that is considered good practice, as this is my first big programming project, and I want to do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a set of functions and you want to specify, by name, which one to use. I'd set up a dictionary mapping the name to the function, and then its just a simple lookup to get the function to use:

```
# Map names to functions. Note there is no need for the names
# to match the actual function name, and the functions can appear
# multiple times.
function_map = {
    'editContactInfo': editContactInfo,
    'editClientInfo': editClientInfo,
    'editAlias': editContactInfo,
}

# Get name of function to run etc. I'm assuming that the function
# name is stored in the variable function_name, and any parameters 
# call it with is in the dictionary parameters (i.e., the functions
# all take keyword arguments).

# Do a lookup to get the function.
try:
    function = function_map[function_name]
except KeyError:
    # Replace with your own error handling code.
    print 'Function {0} does not exist.'.format(function_name)

# Call the function
result = function(**parameters)
```

This is the standard way to do a lookup, which is the what you seem to be asking for. However, you also asked about best practice, and I agree with RestRisiko: using a framework designed for web applications is the best practice in this case.

The only Python framework I have any real experience with is [Django](http://www.djangoproject.org/). This is a 'heavier' (more complex) framework than something like Flask or Bottle, but comes with a lot more inbuilt features. It really depends what your needs are, and I'd recommend checking them all out to see which fits your situation best.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm really novice at all this, and so far everything I've seen regarding web frameworks confuses the hell out of me. I'm mostly doing this out of desire to learn, and plan on reforming it to make it bigger, stronger, faster, better later on. This isn't huge commercially used thing; our company has three employees. I just need something quick and dirty for now while I learn more about frameworks.

Comment: In general, a decent framework will be a lot quicker than writing all the logic from scratch (and has the benefit of lots of testing of security features, database interfaces etc). And it will be a lot harder to clean your dirty solution later on than to learn a framework now (especially if you have to migrate data you store in an ill-advised manner). I'd recommend spending a day going over a good tutorial for the framework(s) that look good to you, and starting things off on the right foot. In the long run you'll be much better off.

Comment: @Tom Thorogood: people used to using frameworks are usually scared of hand-crafted solutions, mainly because of security concerns.  In the case of Django, I learned it as my first web development experience and I've found it faily simple.  They have a **fantastic** book, which is freely available online for you to check it out.  I really suggest you read the first few chapters before trying to hand-craft your own solution.

Answer (score 1):

CGI? This is an ancient culprit of the last century.

Please use a decent Python web-framework for implementing your functionality
in a decent and modern way.

Small framework like Flask or Bottle are much, much, much better than dealing with CGI
nowadays - no excuses please. There is no reason nowadays for using CGI in any way.

Even building something on top of the Python HTTPServer is a much better option.